# AWK if condition

Tags: awk

Given a file `input.txt` with contents:

```
xyMnZnMs76XHgsWJ
size: YN3hxFqFeUxXUMrQ
USPqYEnbquwFhUW7
vhJJduHZu25qHzTw
size: JaTDhQYQtLRWBLjj
uE5HGDAZN6DHU73Q
QxVPfQQaKTgR9LXQ
grnsm8bwSz5fJbQS size:
7CcuZxCHSJYhcdqg
ZuWadAaLWFwDwj5Z
```

how to use `if (condition) {...} else {...}`?

I tried to use:

```bash
awk -F ':' '
IF ($1 ~ /size/) {
    print "match: "$0;
} ELSE {
    print "non-match: "$0;
}' input.txt
```

but all lines are matched (even ones without `$1` containing `"size"`):

```
match: xyMnZnMs76XHgsWJ
match: size: YN3hxFqFeUxXUMrQ
match: USPqYEnbquwFhUW7
match: vhJJduHZu25qHzTw
match: size: JaTDhQYQtLRWBLjj
match: uE5HGDAZN6DHU73Q
match: QxVPfQQaKTgR9LXQ
match: grnsm8bwSz5fJbQS size:
match: 7CcuZxCHSJYhcdqg
match: ZuWadAaLWFwDwj5Z
```

I expect the output to be:

```
non-match: xyMnZnMs76XHgsWJ
match: size: YN3hxFqFeUxXUMrQ
non-match: USPqYEnbquwFhUW7
non-match: vhJJduHZu25qHzTw
match: size: JaTDhQYQtLRWBLjj
non-match: uE5HGDAZN6DHU73Q
non-match: QxVPfQQaKTgR9LXQ
non-match: grnsm8bwSz5fJbQS size:
non-match: 7CcuZxCHSJYhcdqg
non-match: ZuWadAaLWFwDwj5Z
```

Comment: Are you only interested in Awk answers, or other languages as well (sed, Perl, Python, Ruby, Raku, etc.)? You might find an answer in another language that strikes a chord with you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's explain.

The syntax structure for `awk` is « *pattern* `{` *action* `}` », where either component (but not both together) is optional. When you wrote `IF ($1 ~ /size/) { print "match: "$0; }` you were not using the `if` keyword, but were actually concatenating an empty string (the unset variable `IF`) and an expression (`$1 ~ /size/`) that evaluates to either `0` or `1`. Because of the string concatenation the result is considered to be a string ("`0`" or "`1`") and is "true" if it has non-zero length. Either result has a length so the *pattern* condition is considered unconditionally true. At this point the `{` *action* `}` is triggered and you get `print "match: "$0` executed.

Let's fix.

Reading the documentation for `awk` (see `man awk`) you'll find that the `if`…`else` structure is in lower case. Furthermore, you can't use such a structure except inside the « `{` *action* `}` » part of each statement.

```
awk -F: '
    { if ($1 ~ /size/) { print "match:", $0 } else { print "non-match:", $0 } }
' input.txt
```

However, notice that your line `grnsm8bwSz5fJbQS size:` is treated as a non-match in your required output but in this code it's output as a match. This is because the Regular Expression `/size/` matches the first colon-separated field, `grnsm8bwSz5fJbQS size`. You would need to identify the start and end of the string for a precise match - but better would be to compare as a literal string:

```
awk -F: '
    { if ($1 == "size") { print "match:", $0 } else { print "non-match:", $0 } }
' input.txt
```

Or,

```
awk -F: '
    $1 != "size" { print "non-match:", $0 }
    $1 == "size" { print "match:", $0 }
' input.txt
```

Or even,

```
awk -F: '
    $1 != "size" { printf "non-" }
    { print "match:", $0 }
' input.txt
```

Comment: Had they used `if` (properly in lowercase), that would have given a syntax error. Which might not explain the pattern/action -syntax and having to put the statement inside braces, but would in a way be a bit more descriptibe...

Comment: re that last one, you could also do `awk -F: '{ print(($1 != "size" ? "non-" : "") "match", $0) }' input.txt` or so if you're going to golf it...

Comment: @magor I'm trying to work out what your comment is driving at. Do you feel there is something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

For that I wouldn't even use a `if-statement`, they are for more complicated stuff. You could just use do this:

```bash
awk -F':' '/^size/ {print "match: " $0} !/^size/ {print "non-match: " $0}' input.txt
```

or my preferred way is to do it with a variable called `pat`, so you can change it later more easily:

```bash
awk -v pat="size" -F':'  '$1~pat {print "match: " $0}; $1!~pat {print "non-match: " $0}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
`awk -F: '{if ($1 =="size") {print "match: "$0} else {print "non-match: "$0}}'`

With `awk`, you always have to use curly braces for the code, like :

`awk '{ your code }'`

Also the `if`/`else` is not with capital letters.
You can find some further examples [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/).

Comment: The pattern part can include code: the only restriction is that it must be constitute an expression resulting in a boolean value, and not contain braces. It can include a built-in function like `match()` or `index()`, or `gsub ("\047", "\047") % 2` to select lines with mismatched single quotes, or even call user-defined function like `isPrime( $1 + $2)`, or mess with the input like `$0 = sprintf("Wrap %s Done", $0)`, or assign variables like `(j = (NR <=3 ? "Now" : "Later" ))`.